# can't run DrRacket GUI on lubuntu

Tags: bash, lubuntu

I installed DrRacket from the official site and it created me a file with executable file name gracket (inside the bin) which I think is the GUI version of the DrRacket, but when I execute it it does nothing. (it says somthing about missing files: `libjpeg.so.62` and `libpng.so`)

How can I make it run?

Lubuntu 16.10
DrRacket 1.5.3

code:

```
poo@poo-1015PE:~/racket/bin$ ls
drracket      mred-text  mztext      plt-help        racket     slatex
gracket       mzc        pdf-slatex  plt-r5rs        raco       slideshow
gracket-text  mzpp       planet      plt-r6rs        scribble   swindle
mred          mzscheme   plt-games   plt-web-server  setup-plt  tex2page
poo@poo-1015PE:~/racket/bin$ ./gracket
ffi-lib: couldn't open "libjpeg.so.62" (libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

 === context ===
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw/unsafe/jpeg.rkt: [running body]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/bitmap.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/dc.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/svg-dc.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/private/kernel.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/private/const.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/private/check.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/private/mred.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/mred.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/main.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/scheme/gui/base.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/scheme/gui.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/gui/init.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/scheme/gui/init.rkt: [traversing imports]

ffi-lib: couldn't open "libpng.so" (libpng.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

 === context ===
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/private/more-scheme.rkt:166:2: select-handler/no-breaks
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw/unsafe/png.rkt: [running body]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/bitmap.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/dc.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw/private/svg-dc.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/racket/draw.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/private/kernel.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/private/const.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/private/check.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/private/mred.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/poo/racket/collects/mred/mred.rkt: [traversing imports]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the full output you get in your terminal when you attempt to launch the application from there. Vague phrases like "it says something about xy" are not very helpful for troubleshooting. Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander - of course - I just add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing library files `libpng.so` and `libjpeg.so.62` are part of the two packages `libpng-dev` and `libjpeg62`. You should be able to install them by running

```
sudo apt install libpng-dev libjpeg62
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! but now I figured out that is not the DrRacket GUI.. Perhaps you know where is the file that opens the DrRacket GUI?

Comment: I don't have it installed, but maybe the file called `drracket`?